# Exibir valor de outra tela

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Olá estou trabalhando com o seguinte code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversor);
        String t = Double.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("ask"));

    }
```

A string t é um dado que pego de outra activity atraves do codigo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Tela1.this, conversor.class);
                            intent.putExtra("ask",ask);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

O problema é o seguinte só consigo exibir o valor t se estiver dentro do "protected void onCreate" ele só funciona la dentro, como serie pra conseguir pegar o valor fora?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `String t` fora do seu `onCreate()`. Veja:

```
private String t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversor);
    t = Double.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("ask"));
}
```

Ai você pode usar em outras partes do seu código.

Caso você queira usar essa variável em outra *activity*, você pode pode declarar como `public static`:

```
public static String t;
```

Sendo assim, para acessar ela de outra *activity* basta você fazer desta forma:

```
String outroT = OutraActivity.t;
```